# Current Losses in the wire through distance while Transmitting

Tags: current

Please help me to find out the exact losses of current when "three phase system, 400metre length,carrying 220v"?

Comment: You need to know the wire material and cross-section to calculate resistive losses.

Comment: ... and even more information about the cable to calculate its impedance.

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes little sense because *current* is the one thing that is NOT lost by a long transmission line.  Basically, the electrons that go in one end have to come out the other end.  The cable will have a finite resistance, and that times the current will be the voltage drop from one end to the other.  The voltage drop times the current is also the power lost in the cable.

Without more specifics I can't do more than provide the general information above.

Comment: Indeed, *loss of current* makes little sense, but *current loss* could indicate the power loss due to the current in the wire, as you say. That is opposed to leakage loss, that depends on voltage and insulation.